# comparing the character in their numerical representation gone wrong in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string sound;
    if('h'==char(106), 'a'==char(97), 't'==char(114), ' '==char(118),
    'i'==char(105), 's'==char(115))
    //the  numerical representation letter by letter should be "jarvis"  and   
    compare them in "hat is"
    {
        cout << "correct" << endl;//and to my surprise the program shows  it is 
correct
    }
    else
        cout <<"wrong" ;
    return 0;
}
```

I compare the numerical representation of jarvis to hat is and the program show it was correct, how was that possible? what makes the "hat is" the same to jarvis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the correct way to check multiple conditions in an if-else:
what does comma means?AND-condition or maybe OR-condition??

```
if('h'==char(106), 'a'==char(97), 't'==char(114), ' '==char(118),
    'i'==char(105), 's'==char(115))
```

do instead use the boolean operators

```
if('h'==char(106) && 'a'==char(97)...etc)
```

Edit:
remember that doing

```
if (a, b,....,  n){ }
```

is taking the same effect as:

```
if (n){ }
```

this putting apart the wrong conditions you are defining.. (e.g 'h' is no 106 but 104)

Comment: 'h'==char(106) why in the world would you need to write a.program to check this?